# Display alert through vb code Is not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Following is the code to display alert through .vb file but its not working. anybody can help me please.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Test", "<script>alert('" + searchQuery("Cabin").ToString().Trim() + "')</script>")
```

Comment: Does the searchQuery("Cabin").ToString().Trim() contains ' character by any chance ? Also if you try to change it to "<script>alert('baf')</script>" does it give you anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Test", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('" + searchQuery("Cabin").ToString().Trim() + "');</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, and make sure "searchQuery("Cabin").ToString().Trim()" has some value.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(YourPage), "myScripts", 
 "<script language='text/javascript'>alert('" + searchQuery("Cabin").ToString().Trim() + "');</script>");
```